# Aiogram legacy code: TypeError: descriptor '__pydantic_extra__' for 'BaseModel' objects doesn't apply to a 'KeyboardButton' object

Tags: python, typeerror, pydantic, aiogram

```
aiogram==3.1.1
pydantic==2.3.0
pydantic_core==2.6.3
```

---

I've updated aiogram to a newer version and expected magic unicorns to fill my code with amusement. However, now everything that used to be working fails to work due to clashes with pydantic (yes, I've uninstalled all packages related to aiogram, including pydantic, so that it could download a compatible version itself). I have also dealt with imports from parts of aiogram moved elsewhere, so everything should have been fine now.

I fail to run everything, but I suspect this part of the code might contain either a bug or my own mistake:

```
view_profile = KeyboardButton(text='My profile ')
delete_account = KeyboardButton(text='Delete account ')
send_help = KeyboardButton(text='Help ')
show_cards = KeyboardButton(text='Cards ')

main_menu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(view_profile,
                                                          delete_account,
                                                          show_cards,
                                                          send_help)
```

It causes this:

```
File ~/bots/***/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/main.py:165 in __init__
    __pydantic_self__.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(data, self_instance=__pydantic_self__)

TypeError: descriptor '__pydantic_extra__' for 'BaseModel' objects doesn't apply to a 'KeyboardButton' object
```

Having double-checked the documentation, here I am, puzzled and infuriated, as I found no related updates there. Maybe I'm inattentive? Can anyone tell me how to properly assign keys to a keyboard in `aiogram==3.1.1`? Is it a bug or can it be dealt with? I have no desire to downgrade, though the more error messages I receive whatever I do, the more I settle with this idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea how did you get this error *(I could not reproduce it)*, but for sure you are using the old structure.

Shortly, for ReplyKeyboardMarkup you should use this structure:

```
main_menu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[[
            KeyboardButton(text="My profile "), KeyboardButton(text="Delete account " . . .)
            ]]) 

await message.answer("Hello.", reply_markup=main_menu)
```

And for ReplyKeyboardBuilder this one:

```
view_profile = KeyboardButton(text='My profile ')
delete_account = KeyboardButton(text='Delete account ')
send_help = KeyboardButton(text='Help ')
show_cards = KeyboardButton(text='Cards ')
main_menu = ReplyKeyboardBuilder().add(view_profile, delete_account, show_cards, send_help)

await message.answer("Hello.", reply_markup=main_menu.as_markup())
```

Of course you can use loops and other tools to make it more compact and beautiful.
ReplyKeyboardMarkup: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/api/types/reply_keyboard_markup.html
ReplyKeyboardBuilder + few more things: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/utils/keyboard.html.

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue turned out to lie in incompatibility of the old code with new pydantic models for aiogram types. The correct way of putting the piece of code presented in the question is what @w0rraps has written.

Another useful source for those transferring from v2 to v3 is [this official documentation part](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/migration_2_to_3.html), because markups isn't the only sphere it has affected. Many new pleasant features, though.